# Using dynamic library in static framework or using static library in dynamic framework

Tags: ios, frameworks

Static framework become part of the executable, and are statically linked to client apps. What happens if I use a dynamic library when building a static framework? I think it's reasonable that the become executables.

As for dynamic framework, libraries are not part of the executable file. What happens if I use a static framework when building a dynamic framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour will depend on the configuration of the intended host.

If you built an app/framework using a dynamically library say ssl. Then you are assuming the intended host already has this ssl library, and the correct version, installed and available to the app. If it is not the app will not run.

If you use a statically linked library in your app/framework then the app will run regardless of the library being previously installed or not.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Finally understood why it breaks if my host didn't use ``use_framework!`` because I used .tbd in my pods.